# rosbridge, authentication and user roles

Tags: ros-kinetic, rosbridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to create a web interface for my ROS application.

[rosbridge](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbridge_suite) looks promising, however I need to make sure that I can control what a user can interfere with. I am not very experienced in web services.

1. Does [rosbridge](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbridge_suite) come with user authentication and role-dependent access levels?
2. Can I limit what [rosbridge](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbridge_suite) exposes or is every ROS topic and service available for any (malicious) user?
3. [ros_auth](http://wiki.ros.org/rosauth) seems to address some of this, but will it do the job?

(ROS kinetic, Ubuntu 16.04)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280795/rosbridge,-authentication-and-user-roles/) by [knxa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29756/knxa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 811 on 2018-01-25

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> 1 . Does [rosbridge](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbridge_suite) come with user authentication and role-dependent access levels?

No. `rosbridge_suite` only deals with providing the infrastructure to bridge into a ROS nodegraph, nothing more. It is not a web application itself nor is it exclusively used for that.

> 2 . Can I limit what [rosbridge](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbridge_suite) exposes or is every ROS topic and service available for any (malicious) user?

re: limit: yes, in a way: see the [rosapi/readme](https://github.com/RobotWebTools/rosbridge_suite/blob/2150e26c1a0d8ab662e383a09088d149e84b8357/rosapi/README.md). `rosapi` (the component responsible for interfacing with the ROS nodegraph) uses an 'opt-in' list of resources to expose.

This is not linked to any user auth afaik though.

> 3 . [ros_auth](http://wiki.ros.org/rosauth) seems to address some of this, but will it do the job?

I've not used this myself, but it would seem `rosauth` provides a way to do authentication for `rosbridge_suite`. I could not find any documentation on the wiki, but [this comment](https://github.com/GT-RAIL/rosauth/issues/3#issuecomment-24206754) on the issue tracker is rather descriptive:

> [..] rosbridge will wait for an [auth op code](https://github.com/RobotWebTools/rosbridge_suite/blob/2150e26c1a0d8ab662e383a09088d149e84b8357/ROSBRIDGE_PROTOCOL.md#33-authentication-message) to come in. If this is not the first message to come in, or if an invalid token is given, the connection is dropped.

It does seem to have the concept of user *levels*, which does not necessarily translate to role, but is a start.

The UI side of all this is out-of-scope of `rosbridge_suite` though, so that will probably have to be developed. The various `rosjs` and related libraries can probably help there.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-25**:
Note that there is no security in ROS 1, it was never a design requirement. To quote Brian at the ROS-I conference in Stuttgart:

> If you tell me you've found a security issue in ROS 1, you're lying: there is no security.

As `rosbridge_suite` is transparent, it'll have to be made secure.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-25**:
Some experimental work to remedy this situation can be found in [sros](http://wiki.ros.org/SROS).

ROS 2 takes this much further, with full support for (DDS based) security infrastructure such as roles, certificates, authentication and authorisation, access policies etc.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-25**:
You might also be interested in the ROSCon17 presentation *Reactive web interfaces with Polymer and ROS* ([slides](https://roscon.ros.org/2017/presentations/ROSCon%202017%20Web%20Components.pdf), [video](https://vimeo.com/236190796)).

**Comment by [knxa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29756/knxa/) on 2018-01-31**:
Thanks for your thorough reply (as always, where would this forum be without you). I will need to dig more into this.